# AmbiguousViewMatcherException SimpleExoPlayerView Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-espresso

I'm trying to write an Android Espresso Test to check if a video gets played. I'm checking to see if the associated player of my `SimpleExoPlayerView` is playing after I click the play button. The problem is that there is also a `PlaybackControlView` in the hierarchy that has the same id as my `SimpleExoPlayerView` (which I never set so I don't know how it has the same id). How can I specify that I want to test the `SimpleExoPlayerView`?

Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class VideoPlaybackTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMainActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResources() {
        Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mMainActivityTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource());
    }

    @Test
    public void videoIsPlayed() {
        Intents.init();
        onView(withId(R.id.recipes_recycler_view))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
        onView(withId(R.id.steps_recycler_view))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
        onView(withId(R.id.exo_play))
                .perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.simple_video_view))
                .check(new VideoPlaybackAssertion(true));
        Intents.release();
    }

    @After
    public void unregisterIdlingResources() {
        Espresso.unregisterIdlingResources(mMainActivityTestRule.getActivity().getIdlingResource());
    }

}

class VideoPlaybackAssertion implements ViewAssertion {

    private final Matcher<Boolean> matcher;

    //Constructor
    public VideoPlaybackAssertion(Matcher<Boolean> matcher) {
        this.matcher = matcher;
    }

    //Sets the Assertion's matcher to the expected playbck state.
    public VideoPlaybackAssertion(Boolean expectedState) {
        this.matcher = is(expectedState);
    }

    //Method to check if the video is playing.
    @Override
    public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noViewFoundException) {
        if (noViewFoundException != null) {
            throw noViewFoundException;
        }

        SimpleExoPlayerView exoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) view;
        SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer = exoPlayerView.getPlayer();
        int state = exoPlayer.getPlaybackState();
        Boolean isPlaying;
        if ((state == STATE_BUFFERING) || (state == STATE_READY)) {
            isPlaying = true;
        } else {
            isPlaying = false;
        }
        assertThat(isPlaying, matcher);
    }

}
```

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id:
>   com.example.android.bakingapp:id/simple_video_view' matches multiple
>   views in the hierarchy.

The two views that have the same id are my `SimpleExoPlayerView` and a `PlaybackControlView` that I don't really understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this matcher:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.simple_video_view),
  withClassName(is(SimpleExoPlayerView.class.getName())))
```